# Can I track referral traffic in Google Analytics from a domain that is redirecting to my site?

Tags: redirects, tracking, universal-analytics

We have two domains such that www.example.org is redirecting to www.example.com.  We want to track how many times someone gets to example.com from the example.org redirect.   How can do do this in Google Analytics?

Can you add utm tags to the URL in the *.htaccess* file?  Or is there an even better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I use the solution of adding UTM parameters to the redirects.   It is the only thing that I've found that works well with Google Analytics.

When somebody visits my `example.net` domain they get redirected to:

```
http://example.com/?utm_campaign=domainnames&utm_medium=domain&utm_source=example.net
```

Then I can get a "campaign" report in Google Analytics that shows me the visitors:

[image: domain campaign google analytics report]