# Track Google Analytics from a redirected domain using IIS

Tags: google, google-analytics, iis7

I have a olddomain.com that redirects to newdomain.com and we want to know the best way to track how many people are coming from olddomain.com on Google Analytics?

Currently I have two rewrite rules which basically just redirects olddomain.com to newdomain.com like below. What I want to accomplish is to be able to somehow log into Google Analytics and track how many times visitors came from olddomain.com.  I have seen this [article](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/89285/can-i-track-referral-traffic-in-google-analytics-from-a-domain-that-is-redirecti?newreg=cca95cbd0bc34def841d5424ec8a3be7) but its for Apache server using .htaccess.  I would like to know how to do this with IIS 7 using rewrite rules or redirects so GA can track these also.

```
<rule name="Force HTTPS and use production domain - olddomain.com" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^m\.olddomain\.com$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^olddomain\.com$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^ww2\.olddomain\.com$" />
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.olddomain\.com$" />
</conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.newdomain.com{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>



<rule name="Force HTTPS and use production domain - olddomain.com" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^m\.olddomain\.com$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^olddomain\.com$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^ww2\.olddomain\.com$" />
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.olddomain\.com$" />
</conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.newdomain.com{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Somebody on StackOverflow figured out how to append values to the query string when redirecting: [How to append query string & value via IIS rewrite rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311213/how-to-append-query-string-value-via-iis-rewrite-rule).  I'm not sure I understand their solution, nor do I have an IIS server to test it with.

Comment: It looks like you might just be able to append the values using `url="https://www.newdomain.com{REQUEST_URI}?utm_campaign=domainnames&utm_medium=domain&utm_source=olddomain.com"`

Comment: Stephon Ostermiller, I tried implementing it but it just gave me a blank white page.  I was however able to just run `https://www.newdomain.com{REQUEST_URI}?utm_campaign=dom‌​ainnames&utm_medium=‌​domain&utm_source=ol‌​ddomain.com` and it logged into Google.  I think I need to somehow redirect and then rewrite the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your redirected URL to have something like

```
?redirect
```

appended to the end of it. It would have no effect on the page, but in GA you could filter those URLs out to get a count.

Comment: Whenever I do add the url="the_entire_url" the config says its invalid XML.  I tried putting each _utm= parameter into a {QUERYSTRING} and it was valid XML but I still got a blank page on the primary domain name.  This is proving to be very difficult for me to pull off. But I thank you for trying.  BTW, what did you mean appending ?redirect to the end of the url like this "https://www.traveltexas.com/?utm_source=redirected&utm_campaign=301_Redirects_Traveltex&utm_medium=traveltex.com&utm_term=Forwarded?redirect"

Comment: The problem is the ampersands (`&`)in the full URL.     To put them into an XML context you need to escape each one with `&amp;`   So `utm_campaign=My+Campaign&utm_source=Redirect` would become `utm_campaign=My+Campaign&amp;utm_source=Redirect` within the XML configuration document.

Comment: I will try what I have below:

Comment: https://www.newdomain.com/?utm_source=olddomain.com&amp;utm_campaign=301_Redirects&amp;utm_medium=Redirect. I will have to try after I resolve some github dns issues I'm having.