# Site A with 301 redirect to site B not showing Site A as referral in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, 301-redirect, referrer, web-traffic

I am redirecting traffic from `Site A` using 301 redirect to `Site B`. When I am checking traffic stats using Google Analytics I notice traffic in realtime but when I check Source or Referral on it doesn't show Site A as source.

What could be the reason as I need to show client how much traffic is coming from `Site A` to `Site B` as all pages of `Site A` are being redirected to `Site B` home page

Google Analytics shows other website as Referrals  under `Acquisition --> All Traffic --> Referrals` but not `Site A` as referral site.

Does a 301 redirect create and issue for GA to show Site A as referral? I am not sure how I can calculate traffic coming from Site A.

Comment: 301 redirects don't usually appear in the referrer header, so there is no way for Google Analytics to track them that way.  [How to track usage of redirecting domains using either Google Analytics or server logs using Apache](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/102613/how-to-track-usage-of-redirecting-domains-using-either-google-analytics-or-serve) has a solution where you redirect and add `utm` parameters to do the tracking.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, What you said make sense, unfortunately i dont have access to Site A. I will check with client of they are redirect Site A (Wordpress) plugin or rewrite rule with UTM as mentioned in the solution.. I think if they do redirect using WP plugin then i have to check if i can add `http://www.example.com/$1?utm_campaign=domainnames&utm_medium=domain&utm_source=siteA`

Comment: I don't know of a way to track it without access to site A.

Comment: Confirmed from client they are using `.htaccess` for redirect which is good now i can recommend solution advised by you. So following should work `RewriteRule "^/?(.*)"        "http://www.example.com/$1?utm_campaign=domainnames&utm_medium=domain&utm_source=%{HTTP_HOST}" [L,R=301,QSA]`